# Converting an emoji javascript unicode code to utf-8

Tags: javascript, utf-8, character-encoding, emoji

I've got a Javascript string after the user enters a dog-face emoji - U+1F436.

The string seems to be 2 unicode chars - "\ud83d\udc36".

I'm trying to convert this into utf-8. I call javascript encodeURIComponent(string) and that returns a 6-byte string that doesn't seem to be valid utf-8.

I believe the valid utf-8 is 4 bytes long starting with 0xF0.

So how would I convert "\ud83d\udc36" into a valid utf-8 string.

Thanks.

Comment: *"The string seems to be 2 unicode chars"* Specifically, it's two UTF-16 *code units* which form a surrogate pair. (A JavaScript string is actually a series of UTF-16 code units that tolerate invalid surrogate pairs.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function encode_utf8(s) {
  return unescape(encodeURIComponent(s));
}

function decode_utf8(s) {
  return decodeURIComponent(escape(s));
}
```

Comment: i'm getting undefined on unescape. or can you tell me what escape does and I can replicate it.

Comment: The unescape function unescapes a percent-encoded string.  For.e.g.
var e = encodeURIComponent('\u0227'); console.log(e)
"%C8%A7"
var u = unescape(e); console.log(u);
"È§"

Comment: This solution escapes the utf-16 into two %udddd sequences. Ideally, I'd like it to be converted to proper utf-8 - i.e. 4 bytes 0xF0, 0x9F, 0x98, 0x81. But I can use this solution as a backup if I can't - I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Actually I found out that encodeURIComponent() actually does convert the utf16 to utf8 properly (the 4-byte sequence). The problem was on the server.

Comment: Thanks for confirming back as well.

Comment: @lharsh18:can you tell me how to convert \uD83D\uDE0A to 129314 this format?